# Не корректно отображается масть карты

Tags: c#, rider

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Масив карт:

```cs
public static readonly string[] Ranks = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
public static readonly string[] Suits = { "\u2660", "\u2665", "\u2666", "\u2663" };
```

Не до конца отображаются масть карты не нашел информацию как можно поправить?

Весь код:

```cs
public class Card
{
    public static readonly string[] Ranks = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
    public static readonly string[] Suits = { "\u2660", "\u2665", "\u2666", "\u2663" };
    private readonly string _rank;
    private readonly string _suit;

    public Card(string rank, string suit)
    {
        _rank = rank;
        _suit = suit;
    }

    protected Card()
    {
 
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{_rank}{_suit}";
    }
}

public class Deck : Card
{
    private readonly Card[] _cards = new Card[52];
    public Deck() 
    {
        int y = 0;
        foreach (var rank in Card.Ranks)
        {
            foreach (var suit in Card.Suits)
            {
                _cards[y] = new Card(rank, suit);
                y++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shaffle()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = _cards.Length - 5; i >= 1 ; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i + 1);
            (_cards[j], _cards[i]) = (_cards[i], _cards[j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(_cards[50]);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.Shaffle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решил вопрос тем что после юникода надо зажать Alt дописать 255 и появляется код NBSP

UPD
так же есть вариант что можно просто поменять  font family так как родной **jetBrains mono** не подерживает без добавления юникода 255 как указанно выше или багается и не до конца отображает

на остальных видах фонта отображается корректно вроде как попробывал 4 из множества отобразились масти все корекстно  но есть плюс у **jetBrains mono** он автоматически красит все масти карт соотвественно масти )

```
 public static readonly string[] Suits = { "\u2660 ", "\u2665 ", "\u2666 ", "\u2663 " };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd screen
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с простым пробелом не сработало?

Comment: @aepot не пробывал но нашел такой вариант

Comment: @aepot попробывал через пробел не сработало видимо какой то баг что родной font jetbrains Багается писать только в поддержку и узнавать) ну нашел 2 варианта ответа выше